# Using a previously-rendered .pdf as a subfigure

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, plot

Suppose that I have a previously-rendered plot in pdf format. The code used to generate it is not available. I would like to render this `external.pdf` as a subfigure in a larger, composite plot. For example, using [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html) I might want to do

```
library( ggplot2 )

## A <- ...how to load external.pdf here?
B <- ggplot( iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width) ) + geom_point()

cowplot::plot_grid(A, B, labels=c("A","B")) + ggsave("composite.pdf")
```

Is there a way to load and render `external.pdf`, while preserving its vector graphics format?

**"Data"**:

```
ggplot( mtcars, aes(x=wt,y=mpg) ) + geom_point() + ggsave("external.pdf")
```

Comment: Maybe use `grConvert` to convert PDF to SVG and then use `grImport2` to import the SVG as a grid object. See here for more info: https://sjp.co.nz/projects/grimport2/grImport2.html?